# no such method error for animation withendaction method android

Tags: android, listview, animation, android-animation

Hi I am developing small android application in which i want to do swipe delete for list row. For that I am using view on touch listener and deleting row with some animation. Everything is working fine except `withendaction()` method which gives no such a method error. I know it supports above the api level 16 and I set my required api levels according to that i tried it in following ways:

```
private View.OnTouchListener mTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {

@Override
public boolean onTouch(final View v, MotionEvent event) {

    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

    break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
    break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

    break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
    {
            v.animate().setDuration(duration).
                    alpha(endAlpha).translationX(endX).
                    withEndAction(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                        }
                    });


        }
    }
    break;
    default: 
    return false;
    }
    return true;
}
};
```

my all animation working fine but at the point of withendaction method it gives error that is `no such a method` 
Am i doing something wrong? Need help.

Thank you.

Comment: I think this the method in ViewProperty Animator http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator.html#withEndAction%28java.lang.Runnable%29 . Are you using any sub-class of View animator (ViewFlipper...etc)

Comment: Thank you for replay. my xml contains simple relative layout with list view and in row view I am using simple image view and text view. I am using custom adapter for displaying my list view. So is this the right way to do this or i have to do something else. Need help . thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you're have want to support API 9 device you can't use the View.animate() features.

You'll have to use the older animation framework, like `AlphaAnimation`.

Example code to fade-in your button:

```
    AlphaAnimation anim = new AlphaAnimation(0f, endAlpha);
    anim.setDuration(duration);

    anim.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            // Do stuff on animation end
        }
    });

    v.startAnimation(anim);
```

If you want it to animate view translation as well, you'll need to add another animation like this using `TranslateAnimation`

Answer (score 0):

This call is supported from API level 15. So if you're trying it on any earlier SDK versions it will throw the said Exception

Comment: Hi sir thank you for replay. i am setting min sdk version as 9 and target as 16 and I ran this project on device with android version 4.x. So how to solve this problem. Need help. thank you.

Comment: Since your min SDK version is 9, you should find an alternative for this method as it will not work on any device running API level under 15 (like the device you've tested on). Check if it exists in the support library or try googling for an alternative:http://androiddev.orkitra.com/?p=12771

Comment: Thank sit for the help. Any alternative method for this that mean swipe delete row of list which will work on older version also

Answer (score 0):

i think view.animate is for:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR1)
```

for

```
< API 12
```

use the nineoldandroid library